# How to make preferredStatusBarStyle a function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app has 12 ViewControllers and for each one I'd like the status bar to be changed from a settings page.
Right now I do it with a function that I have put into a Class "CommonFuncs" which I then call from each ViewController:

```
CommonFuncs.setStatusBarColor()
```

which uses this deprecated call:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

This lets me set the statusBar for the all Views in the app from a Settings page using a single call.

Now I need to update and remove the deprecated function, however it appears that the replacement requires code for each ViewController:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if activeForeColorName == "white"{
        return .lightContent
    }else if activeForeColorName == "black"{
        return .default
    }else{
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

plus this refresh I use in viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

This is a real pain since the same code needs to be put into 12 separate ViewControllers.

Is there any way to move this code into a function, or use another status bar call that applies to the entire app?

Answer (score 0):

You can move that in a UIViewController extension, f.e.

```
extension UIViewController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if Configs.statusBarColor == "black"{
            return .default
        } else {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }

    //swizzle viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods and observe for statusBar color change notifications 

    //...
    //swizzling code here...
    //...       

    func swizzledViewWillAppear(_animated: Bool) {
        self.swizzledViewDidLoad(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateStatusBarAppearance), name: NSNotification.Name("updateStatusBarColorNotification"), object: nil)
    }

    func swizzledViewWillDisappear(_animated: Bool) {
        swizzledViewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func updateStatusBarAppearance() {
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }    
}
```

Then just post a notification with name `updateStatusBarColorNotification` whenever you change the `Configs.statusBarColor` (or in your case its activeForeColorName)

Comment: Extensions should never the used to override existing functionality.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree with you, there are some existing functionalities overriding which in extensions may lead to an unexpected behavior. But I think `preferredStatusBarStyle` isn't included in that list. Anyways, the safer way will be making a base class, do that job there, and make all your VCs inherit from that class. But the above solution will work for most cases.